# The chance of the word to be of all different letters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A four letter word is written down by taking letters from the word KANYAKUMARI.What is the chance of the word to be of all different letters?

---

Since KANYAKUMARI has K,K,A,A,A,N,Y,U,M,R,I letters in which there are 2 K's and 3 A's.The chance that the four letter word to be of all different letters$=\frac{m}{n}$,where $m=\binom{8}{4}$,because there are 8 different letters K,A,N,Y,U,M,R,I.and $n=\binom{11}{4}$.So probability$=\frac{7}{33}$,but the correct answer is $\frac{840}{1109}$.I dont know where i have made the mistake.Please help me.

Comment: I think, for the numerator, $inclution-exclution$ will help most.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I tried working this problem using your suggestion of a probability model, which seemed the most reasonable one to me; but is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: I think the idea is fine, but the counting (for the numerator) is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your response. If we look at a simpler example, such as DECIDE, wouldn't there be 4 ways to choose 4 tiles with all different letters (instead of $\binom{4}{4}=1$ way) out of the total of $\binom{6}{4}=15$ selections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take permutations into account.

If we take the 8 distinct letters, there will be $\binom{8}{4}*4!= 1680$ distinct words

If we take all the 11 letters, the number of distinct words will be given by:

coefficient of $x^4$ in $4!(1+x)^6(1+x+x^2/2!)(1+x+x^2+x^3/3!)= 2218$

[Or else enumerate words that are  $3-1$ of a kind, $2-2$ of a kind, $2-1-1$ of a kind, etc]

$Pr = \dfrac{1680}{2218} = \dfrac{840}{1109}$

Answer (score 2):

**Favourable cases**

Here we have $8$ distinct letters , Then there will be $\displaystyle \binom{8}{4}\times 4! = 1680$

Here $\bf{KANYAKUMARI}$ contain $\bf{2K,3A,N,Y,U,M,R,I}$

Now **Total no. of cases**

$\bullet\; $ If all letters are different, Then we will take $4$ different letters

So total no. of arrangement $\displaystyle = \underbrace{\binom{8}{4}}_{\bf{select\; 4\; diff.\; letters}}\times \underbrace{4!}_{\bf{arrange\; these\; 4\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ If $2$ letters are same and other $2$ letters are different.

So we will take a $1$ pair of letter from $2$ pair letter and other $2$ from $7$ different letters

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle =\underbrace{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{7}{3}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{4!}{2!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ same letters are of same kind and other $2$ are of same kind

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle \underbrace{\binom{2}{2}\times \binom{6}{2}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ Here $3$ same letter are of same kind and other $1$ letter is different

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle = \underbrace{\binom{1}{1}\times \binom{7}{1}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{4!}{3!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

So Total no. of ways $\displaystyle $ Sum of all above cases $\displaystyle =2218 $

So Required probability $\displaystyle = \frac{\bf{favourable\; cases}}{\bf{Total\; no.\; of \; ways}}$

Comment: Your logic is right,but your total number of ways add up to 2638 instead of 2218.Total number of ways in second case should be$=2\times \binom{7}{2}\frac{4!}{2!}$ and total number of ways in third case should be $=\binom{2}{2}\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ @juantheron.

Answer (score 2):

Following Andre Nicolas's suggestion, we think of the letters as being on 11 "Scrabble" tiles, with all combinations of tiles equally likely, and with the tiles for the A's (and K's) painted with different colors.

Since each selection of 4 tiles can be arranged in $4!$ ways, we can disregard the ordering of the tiles,

so we get the probability that all 4 letters are distinct is given by

$\hspace{.3 in}\displaystyle\frac{\binom{6}{4}+2\binom{6}{3}+3\binom{6}{3}+6\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{11}{4}}=\frac{205}{330}=\frac{41}{66}$

by considering the cases

$\;\;\;\;$1) no A's, no K's $\;\;$2) 1K, no A $\;\;$ 3) 1 A, no K $\;\;$ 4) 1A, 1K

Comment: Your method is good. Under the natural "Scrabble tile" model it gives the right answer in an efficient way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks - I appreciate your looking at this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at it a bit differently.
Suppose you have a bag of balls. The color distribution is

```
6 White
3 Red
2 Blue
```

What is the probability that if you grab 4 random balls, without replacement, that you have no more than one red ball, and no more than one blue ball?

Edit: This will only work if the original question is not allowing the reusing of letters. I am unsure from how it is currently phrased.